# how to flag data that has characters outside some range in php

Tags: php, regex, validation, symfony

I'm building a simple validation system that flags a string if it has characters outside of the accepted range. I was hoping to use some pattern matching function that would do this like ...

```
// if data contains anything that is not [A-Z][a-z] or [0-9] the function returns false or an exception
preg_flag_bad_data("[A-Z][a-z][0-9]",$data)
```

Comment: You want us to write the function for you?

Comment: Do you mean you want a regex that doesn't match if there are any illegal characters

Comment: Do a quick search before asking. If you had you'd have found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735972/php-fastest-way-to-check-for-invalid-characters-all-but-a-z-a-z-0-9?rq=1 which has exactly what you are wanting

Comment: He just wants a PCRE inverse range match.

Comment: I was hoping that I wouldn't have to write the function since I imagine that this is a very common task in php. Is there something out there that will easily do this for me, or will I be forced into writing this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

preg_match will do exactly this for you

```
preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9]*$/", $subject);
```

No need to create a new function