# How to filter out special characters created by an array when filling out name portion of an email in php

Tags: php, html

I have built an email app (?) and I want special characters (eg. !@£$%^) to be filtered out, when a user submits the form.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];

$to = "hm_087@hotmail.com";
$subject = "Test";
$message  = $name;

$invalid= array("@","!","#");

if (($_POST['name'])!== $invalid[0]){
    mail($to, $subject, $message);
    echo 'Message sent';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid character entered';
}

?>
```

As you can see, I created an array to do this, but I am limited to filter out only one special character (i.e. the @ character). Any way in which I can choose all the characters from an array to be filtered out?

Comment: _“but I am limited to filter out only one special character (ie. the @ character)”_ - you are not only limited to that, your filter also completely fails, if `$_POST['name']` was not _exactly_ `@`, and _just_ that. `foo@bar` already passes your “test” with fyling colors …

Comment: Loop over your array, and check if the value _contains_ the character you are currently checking on. If you don’t know how to check if a text _contains_ a specific character, do a bit of research on that.

Comment: Regular expressions would also be a way to do stuff like this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735972/php-fastest-way-to-check-for-invalid-characters-all-but-a-z-a-z-0-9

Comment: Please be more specific about which characters you want to allow in the messages. Are numbers allowed? Punctuation characters? Brackets? Quote marks? Apostrophes? If you can give an exact list of allowed or disallowed, then you can do this easily via regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a regular expression to character match.

```
if (!preg_match('/[!@£$%^]/', $name)) {
    mail($to, $subject, $message);
    echo 'Message sent';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid character entered';
}
```

Here it's checking for the characters `!@£$%^` you specifically mentioned in your question, but *"I want special characters to be filtered out"* is a bit vague, and I suspect you mean to include a few more characters in this. If you can be more specific about which characters you want to allow, we can refine the regex.